# Go template can't call method on field

Tags: templates, go, go-templates

I have a wrapper around `net/mail.Address` that provides some marshalling logic. I'm trying to use it in a template, but I keep getting `can't evaluate field String in type EmailAddress`. The template docs say:

> The name of a niladic method of the data, preceded by a period,
>   such as
>
> .Method
>
> The result is the value of invoking the method with dot as the
>   receiver, dot.Method().

and

> Method invocations may be chained and combined with fields and keys
>   to any depth:
>
> .Field1.Key1.Method1.Field2.Key2.Method2

So with that in mind I've written this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "net/mail"
    "os"
)

type EmailAddress struct{ mail.Address }

type emailFormatter struct {
    From         EmailAddress
    To           EmailAddress
}

var tmpl = template.Must(template.New("Sample Text").Parse("From: {{.From.String}}\r" + `
To: {{.To.String}}` + "\r" + `
Content-Type: text/html` + "\r" + `
Subject: Sample Text` + "\r\n\r" + `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Sample Text</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
    Sample Text
</body>
</html>
`));

func main() {
    to := EmailAddress{
        mail.Address{
            Address: "em@i.l",
            Name: "",
        },
    }
    from := EmailAddress{
        mail.Address{
            Address: "no-reply@test.quest",
            Name: "",
        },
    }

    fmt.Println(to.String()) //outputs (as expected) "<em@i.l>"
    fmt.Println(from.String()) //outputs (as expected) "<no-reply@test.quest>"

    f := emailFormatter{
        To: to,
        From: from,
    }

    var buff bytes.Buffer
    if err := tmpl.Execute(&buff, f); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error: %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Println(buff.String())
}
```

I've separately verified that calling `EmailAddress.String` is totally legal, so I can't figure out why the only output of this is:

```
Error: template: Sample Text:1:13: executing "Sample Text" at <.From.String>: can't evaluate field String in type main.EmailAddress
```

## EDIT

At a commenter's suggestion I changed the calls from `.From.String` and `.To.String` to `.From.Address.String` and `.To.Address.String`, because

> *"`String` isn't defined on `EmailAddress`, it's defined on `EmailAddress.Address`"*

but the result is the same:

```
Error: template: Sample Text:1:13: executing "Sample Text" at <.From.Address.String>: can't evaluate field String in type mail.Address
```

Comment: Because `String` isn't defined on `EmailAddress`, it's defined on `EmailAddress.Address`.

Comment: Then why can I call `EmailAddress.String` above that?

Comment: I believe this is a pointer receiver problem. What happens if you make `From` and `To` a `*EmailAddress`?

Comment: ... or just pass in `&f` instead of `f` to `Execute`.

Comment: _"or just pass in `&f` instead of `f` to `Execute`"_ - that did it, @mkopriva you wanna write an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [`String`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/mail/#Address.String) is defined with a pointer receiver you need to pass an "addressable" instance of `mail.Address` to the template to be able to execute that method.

You can do this by passing in a pointer to `f`.

```
if err := tmpl.Execute(&buff, &f); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Or you can do it by passing in pointer to `EmailAddress`.

```
type emailFormatter struct {
    From *EmailAddress
    To   *EmailAddress
}

// ...

f := emailFormatter{
    To:   &to,
    From: &from,
}

// ...

if err := tmpl.Execute(&buff, f); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Or by passing in a pointer to `mail.Address`.

```
type EmailAddress struct{ *mail.Address }

// ...

to := EmailAddress{
    &mail.Address{
        Address: "em@i.l",
        Name: "",
    },
}
from := EmailAddress{
    &mail.Address{
        Address: "no-reply@test.quest",
        Name: "",
    },
}

f := emailFormatter{
    To:   to,
    From: from,
}

// ...

if err := tmpl.Execute(&buff, f); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

---

Note that the reason you don't need to do that in the Go code is because there the compiler does it for you.

For example:

```
fmt.Println(to.String())
```

becomes:

```
fmt.Println((&to).String())
```

> A method call x.m() is valid if the method set of (the type of) x
>   contains m and the argument list can be assigned to the parameter list
>   of m. **If x is addressable and &x's method set contains m, x.m() is
>   shorthand for (&x).m()**